# When bailing out of a T6 what is the intended path that the pilot clears the horizontal stabilizer?

Tags: fixed-wing, parachute

My wife and I who have both flown in vintage T-6's in the rear seat have been given instructions to stand on the seat and "dive toward the wing" in the event we need to bail out of the aircraft.

We've haven't been able to agree how a pilot is expected to exit the aircraft and clear the horizontal and vertical stabilizers.

If a pilot bails out of a T-6 is their path supposed to clear the horizontal stabilizer laterally or to pass underneath the horizontal stabilizer as the aircraft passes over?

We've done some basic math and guesstimates but still can't come to a consensus. Can someone with theoretical or real experience in bailouts with non-ejection aircraft help to clarify this?

Comment: Good question (and thanks for the edit) -- welcome to Aviation.SE!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was jumping many years ago. You will travel almost at the T6's speed momentarily as you fall, so if it's flying level at 1G when you go over the side, you drop straight away behind the wing trailing edge without much risk of hitting the tail.

Watch any skydive exit video and observe how fast the jumpers go straight down relative to the airplane.

It gets riskier if the Gs are less than 1, say if the airplane is climbing and arcing over as you exit. When I was skydiving in the 70s, a friend foolishly tried an experiment, exiting the jump plane while the pilot pushed over, hoping to float alongside momentarily.

Instead, being in a near ballistic arc, the drag just took him straight back alongside the airplane and the horizontal tail just contacted the top of his helmet, giving him some stars in his vision, and putting a small dent in the LE of the tail. He never tried that again.

Comment: That reminds me of my first time disembarking an aircraft in flight; I had a mental picture of floating away into the distance but in fact I dropped like a brick.  I’ve understood that we’re told ’aim for the trailing edge’ on the understanding that we won’t actually do it but will aim just behind.

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense for straight and level flight! I'm not sure why I didn't think of skydiving when thinking about this problem.

As you mention, however if the aircraft was uncontrollable and diving (which would probably be when you'd be jumping in an emergency) that complicates things and might be too open ended a question.

I suppose as long as you get out even if you get whacked it's better than riding an uncontrollable aircraft to the ground. And maybe that's the answer "it depends, but it's better than staying in".

Thanks!

Comment: @tsjackson ... And always remember, any landing you can walk away from is a great one.

Comment: @Sharpenologist Wasn't that the definition of a good landing? I thought a great landing is one after which the aircraft can be used again.

Comment: @TooTea ... I stand corrected!

Comment: @John-K Thanks again, I was able to confirm with an airshow and reno air race pilot who we know that flies a T-6 that this is the intention when bailing out